# AWS EC2 autoscaling without constant alarms?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have created the following two alerts for an autoscaling group:

- Scale **up** 1 instance if "CPUUtilization >= 75%" changes to state **ALARM**
- Scale **down** 1 instance if "CPUUtilization >= 30%" changes to state **OK**

I have chosen to trigger the scale down event on **OK** to not have a constant ALARM in Cloudwatch if load is below 30%. On the other hand that is exactly the issue. When an upscale happens leaving the group with an average load **between** 30% and 75% the state is set to ALARM.

Is there any way to configure Cloudwatch to trigger scale up and down events properly without being left with an ALARM state after the scaling happened?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this: CPUUtilization <= 30%" changes to state OK?

Comment: The alarm fires when CPU >= 30%, so I need to downscale when the state changes to OK (which happens when CPU < 30%).

Comment: @kev Did you manage to find something? I'd also like a better solution.

Comment: @musiKk unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

The "Scale down" operation should be set to "CPUUtilization < 75%" (state OK), and don't worry about leaving the group without machines, though you have a min number of instances and it does not go beyond that.

Comment: I will have machines constantly spinning up and down if I do that. Lets say I have 1 machine with CPU = 80% -> scale up -> 2 machines with 40% -> scale down -> back to 1 machine with 80% etc.

Comment: I have a running group in a production environment that works the following way: There is an alarm in cloudwatch with a threshold of CPUUtilization >= 70 for 10 minutes , so if CPUUtilization >= 70 then state ALARM, if CPUUtilization < 70 then state OK. In ALARM state add 6 instances and in OK state remove 1 instance in periods of 5 minutes until reach the min. I recommend you to set up the alarm directly in Cloudwatch and then use it in the setup of the scaling policies, instead of setup a new alarm thourgh the policies.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Assuming I have 4 boxes max. Starting with one box on 80% ALARM -> spin up all 4 boxes, 20% load each. Every 5 minutes one of the boxes gets removed until 2 are left with 40% which is still OK so another one gets removed. Which takes us back to one box at 80% and the whole process starts over. Your approach works for burst load though if you are sure you will go back to one box below 70% within half an hour.

Comment: If you always have one machine over 80%, consider at least on of these two options: a) Use a bigger/better machine so the CPU usage is initially lower, or b) use a base min of 2-3 machines to always start running from a lower CPU usage. In our case we had to use both, vertical and horizontal scaling to begin with a secure and low CPU usage.

Comment: Scaling policy and alarm period should be based on the load and the nature of the load of the application. For ex : if the load is bursting and short lived you can scale in and out more aggressively,  if the load increase is more gradual your scaling policy should be more conservative.  Also cool down periods with simple scaling policy (or warm up periods with step or target tracking scaling policy ) can be used to prevent frequent scale in and scale out activities.