# Fargate autoscaling with AWS CDK 2. results in downscaling Alarm to be constantly "in Alarm" state

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling

As I understand the [documentation and example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_autoscaling-readme.html#step-scaling) with this setting

```
autoScalingGroup.scaleOnMetric('ScaleToCPU', {
  metric: workerUtilizationMetric,
  scalingSteps: [
    { upper: 10, change: -1 },
    { lower: 50, change: +1 },
    { lower: 70, change: +3 },
  ],

  // Change this to AdjustmentType.PERCENT_CHANGE_IN_CAPACITY to interpret the
  // 'change' numbers before as percentages instead of capacity counts.
  adjustmentType: autoscaling.AdjustmentType.CHANGE_IN_CAPACITY,
});
```

you will have the downscaling alarm (with upper bound 10%) permanently in state "In Alarm" when you reached the minimum number of instances and use less of 10% CPU, right?

[image]

I read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320715/aws-ec2-autoscaling-without-constant-alarms) and it is suggesting the exact same: make the Action to switch to state "Ok".

Moreover, with this CDK construct we don't have any chance to do anything from the comment section of the above mentioned SO post.

So, I just wanted to confirm that this permanent "In Alarm" state in our Cloudwatch console is the intended situation.

Comment: That looks like EC2 auto-scaling, not Fargate. But in any case, yes, when you have 2 alarms for auto-scaling (1 for scale-up, 1 for scale-down) one of those alarms will always be in alarm. That's why the AWS CloudWatch Metrics console has a checkbox to hide auto-scaling alarms.

Comment: right, thanks for clarification. I found "Hide Auto Scaling alarms" in Alarm Dashboard and even the red exclamation marks on the navigation menu disappear. This will do for me.